# How do you make Ubuntu install usb stick run in text mode?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

How do you make Ubuntu install usb stick run in text mode? I have a ubuntu 15.04 install usb.

The computer is a HP Envy 17 with Nvidia GTX850M, Optimus.

When booting from the stick, it has thousands of error messages about nouveau. Well it's Optimus so it shouldn't even be trying to run nouveau, it should use i915.

How do you make a Ubuntu install usb stick start up with i915 or just in plain text? Or how do you stop it from trying to use nouveau?

Comment: If you hit escape button once you get to purple screen, you can see a menu where you can change boot options.  I don't quite remember all of them, but there should be an option to install with base video settings. Also, Ctrl + Alt + F2 to get into console